# How can I localize my Meteor JS App?

Tags: meteor, internationalization

I need to get my Meteor JSapp in more than one language. 
What would be the best approach for i18n? 
Google passed my quite a bit of results but reading them I am more confused than happy. There a many hacks but is there a settled solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a comment than an answer (however my repu still is too low :o):

Localization normally is only needed client side (there are exceptions but not many and they can be dealt with) and as Meteor is quite young with an own templating engine it's normal that you find more hacks than stable solutions.

However you can doge that bullet by using an older client side templating technique than Meteors built in one like AngularJS with Angular-Meteor (http://angularjs.meteor.com/). Personally I can just recommend this project as it gives you a lot more power than Blaze alone does. And now when you look for solutions for localizing AngularJS you will find a lot more. One I can recommend is angular-gettext (https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/) which also comes with a grunt script to extract and compile your strings in one click and which builts a .pot file so that you can translate your app with PoEdit just like you would with an old school webapplication. The only thing you may need to do yourself is to extend the grunt script to parse for any custom translation functions you may add (but maybe you can live without those than you wouldn't need to do anything).

Comment: Thank you very much this what I was looking for. Simple and clean. Got it to work in 15min.